# Writing MakeFeatureLayer_management Where Clause With Multiple Mixed Values using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers, where-clause

I am trying to select certain points in a shape file using three different fields. Two fields don't need to vary, but the third one (the `analog_years` variable below) does. I want to be able to select different values and numbers of years for this variable.

```
analog_years = [1950, 1993, 2010]

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hurr_p_data_01, "lfalls_01",'"BASIN" = \'NA\'' " AND " '"USA_RECORD" = \'L\'')
```

How do I also include the `analog_years` variable in the where clause or is there a way to write a where clause variable for all three and just reference that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use AddFieldDelimiters and format.

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
> format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
> shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
> square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
> delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
> the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
> ones

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\fc'
analog_years = [1950, 1993, 2010]
sql = """{0}='NA' AND {1}='L' AND {2} IN{3}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field='BASIN'), arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, 'USA_RECORD'), arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, 'YEAR_FIELD'), tuple(analog_years))
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='somelyr', where_clause=sql)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! It looks like there are a few ways to go about this. I'll try several of them to help me get a hang of SQL.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That works great.

Answer (score 3):

[@AnnaForrest's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/378409/115) is almost there.

You need to quote properly in SQL, have a look at my answer [Generating a SQL statement from a text file to make a selection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378312/generating-a-sql-statement-from-a-text-file-to-make-a-selection/378314#378314) for the syntax, `whereclause = "NAME IN ('{}')".format("','".join(list_of_strings))`... look closely at the quotes, python doesn't care if you use single or double as long as they're matched, SQL does, it must be a single quote for strings in SQL so in python start/end with a double when creating definition queries and then you can use as many single quotes in that string as you like with needing to escape them in the form `\'`.

Although many examples of definition queries have quotes or brackets around field names the truth is you really don't need them for a selection query, just use the field names and the query will work with shapefiles, personal/file/enterprise geodatabases and tables - that saves a lot of quote-in-quote-out guessing (is this one for SQL or for python?) to having both ends double and then every single inside is for SQL!

As analog_years is already a list but numbers and not strings the join function will have a dummy spit which is why Anna has tried list comprehension `str(x) for x in analog_years`  but is missing the beginning and terminating list brackets, that should be [str(x) for x in analog_years] as a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension); I generally avoid using comprehension for new users as it's really confusing what's actually happening, for a new user try

```
YearsAsStrings = [] # an empty list
for ThisYear in analog_years:
  YearsAsStrings.append(str(ThisYear)) # add the string of the year to the list
analog_years = YearsAsStrings          # copy back to your original variable as strings
```

To select all those years:

```
# as list comprehension
analog_years = [1950, 1993, 2010]    
QF = "BASIN = 'NA' AND USA_RECORD = 'L' AND YEAR_FIELD  IN ('{}')".format("','".join([str(x) for x in analog_years]))    
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hurr_p_data_01, "lfalls_01",QF)
```

-or-

```
# as list building - easier to see what's happening here.
analog_years = [1950, 1993, 2010]

YearsAsStrings = [] # an empty list
for ThisYear in analog_years:
    YearsAsStrings.append(str(ThisYear)) # add the string of the year to the list
analog_years = YearsAsStrings          # copy back to your original variable as strings
QF = "BASIN = 'NA' AND USA_RECORD = 'L' AND YEAR_FIELD IN ('{}')".format("','".join(analog_years))

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hurr_p_data_01, "lfalls_01",QF)
```

-or to loop through each year, selecting only that year-

```
for ThisYear in analog_years:
    QF = "BASIN = 'NA' AND USA_RECORD = 'L' AND YEAR_FIELD = {}".format(ThisYear)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hurr_p_data_01, "lfalls_01",QF)
```

Note: if your date field isn't a string then don't quote the values for SQL, the IN operator would work like `"YEAR_FIELD IN (1950, 1993, 2010)"`

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning Python syntax but I don't know SQL at all. That helps a lot!

Comment: I've tried both the list comprehension and YearsAsStrings methods and I'm getting the same error: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression BASIN = 'NA' AND USA_RECORD = 'L' AND SEASON IN ('1950','1993','2010'). The field name for the years is SEASON, I updated your code with that name.

Comment: The years are short integers, which quotes do I drop in `sql = "BASIN = 'NA' AND USA_RECORD = 'L' AND SEASON IN ('{}')".format("','".join([str(x) for x in analog_years]))`?

Comment: Ah, yes - you're right.  I pulled my example from some code I'd written and simplified to suit, but clearly missed that :) Will fix my answer so as not to cause confusion...

Comment: More pythonic way would be “,”.join(map(unicode, analog_years))

Comment: Hello, can anyone please help me with the error I'm getting? I think It's related to the years in the SEASON field being an integer but I'm not sure. I've tried dropping various sets of quote but I still get the error. Thanks!

Comment: QF = "BASIN = 'NA' AND USA_RECORD = 'L' AND YEAR_FIELD IN ({})".format(",".join(analog_years)) should work if the YEAR_FIELD (SEASON in your case) is an integer. The IN operator doesn't work so well for floats or doubles.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate your values into a whereclause like this:

```
whereclause = "FIELD_NAME IN (" +  ",".join([str(x) for x in analog_years]) + ")"
```

If you're working with a string field you'll need to put single quotes around the values as well.

Comment: Do I just declare `whereclause` like that and then tack it on to the end of the where clause section in my original statement? Or, do I need to add my other two fields to 'whereclause`?

Comment: You will need to modify the above to suit your specific use case.  I prefer to consolidate all my criteria into a single whereclause variable, that I can print out to see its correct (and copy/paste into a select by attributes if needed to confirm results).  Then I just pass the single whereclause to the MakeFeatureLayer function.

Comment: It's enough to str(tuple(list)) instead of bulky join.